# jQuery .validate() submitHandler not called

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add a little custom validation to a form using the jQuery Validation plugin (at least one checkbox must be checked).

Unfortunately, the submitHandler in .validate() is not being called at all.  I'm sure it's a simple issue, but I can't spot it.  I have reduced the problem in the following Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/xcmtc/3/

The desired result is that

```
alert('Form Validation OK.');
```

executes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I stumbled upon the correct answer after googling and trying things for a few hours...

> Microsoft’s jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js cripples jQuery.validation so that most of it’s configuration options simply don’t work any more. Neither with the $.validate.setDefaults() nor with the $(‘#element’).validate() methods.

http://www.tigraine.at/2011/08/26/jquery-validate-and-microsofts-unobtrusive-validation-dont-play-well-together/